Isolate 2 power sources to the same device
I have an electric lock that operates with 12v DC input and I need to have 2 different power sources due to different use cases.
How can I isolate the circuits in order to prevent to inject current on the power source 1 when I activate the 2nd and vice-vesa.
The use case is the electric lock to be activated by a video doorbell but I also need a separate push button (that I will connect with a  12v power supply)
Edit: Did some research and came up to this:

Does it make sense? Can 2 different power supplies share the same V-?
Note: I'm not fluent in electrical stuff
Thanks

Just use a SPDT pushbutton:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

What if the doorbell uses a low side switch and steering diode across NPN to V+

Well this solution with the SPDT pushbutton seems good and simple, unfortunately for my use case it would be hard to implement because the lock is away from the place of the button and I just have 2 free wires in the corrugated pipe
